# E/GraphResponse: Unsupported get request. Android Studio facebook login

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have problem with Facebook login app. I was fallowing this  [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTs3GEuBwXc&t=181s)  . I took every step and on the end i converted MainAcktivity into kotlin file. Application after login in or logout is stopping.
and I'm receiving follow error in Logcat:

```
2021-05-22 19:23:12.963 9521-9545/com.example.XXX_login E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID '111111111111111' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}
    2021-05-22 19:23:46.065 9521-9521/com.example.XXX_login E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.XXX_login, PID: 9521
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter oldAccessToken
            at com.example.XXX_login.MainActivity$accessTokenTracker$1.onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(Unknown Source:2)
            at com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker$CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(AccessTokenTracker.java:110)
            at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:313)
            at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:121)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Here is my MainActivity.kt file:

```
  package com.example.XXX_login
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.facebook.*
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
import org.json.JSONException
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso as Picasso1

//import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private var callbackManager: CallbackManager? = null
  private lateinit var loginButton: LoginButton
  private var imageView: ImageView? = null
  private var textView: TextView? = null
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button)
    textView = findViewById(R.id.tv_name)
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.tv_profilePic)
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

    //permisions do logowania
    loginButton.setPermissions(
      listOf(
        "user_gender",
        "email",
        "user_location",
        "user_birthday"
      )
    )
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult?> {
      override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult?) {
        Log.d("Demo", "Zalogowano!")
      }

      override fun onCancel() {
        Log.d("Demo", "Wylogowano")
      }

      override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
        Log.d("Demo", "Bład logowania:")
      }
    })
  }

  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    callbackManager!!.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    val graphRequest =
      GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()) { `object`, response ->

        //tworzenie pliku JSON z pobieranymi przez Graph danymi
        Log.d("Demo", `object`.toString())
        try {
          val name = `object`.getString("name")
          val pic = `object`.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url")
          textView!!.text = name
          Picasso1.get().load(pic).into(imageView)
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
          e.printStackTrace()
        }
      }
    val bundle = Bundle()
    //informacjie pozyskiwane z facebooka= defaultowe i na podstawie wcześniej wydanych permissions
    bundle.putString(
      "fields",
      "gender, name, first_name, last_name, email, birthday, location, picture"
    )
    graphRequest.parameters = bundle
    graphRequest.executeAsync()
  }

  //tracker do sprawdzania czy użytkownik jest zalogowany, jestli token sie zmieni to wywowała sie ta metoda
  //wylogowywanie sie
  var accessTokenTracker: AccessTokenTracker = object : AccessTokenTracker() {
    override fun onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
      oldAccessToken: AccessToken,
      currentAccessToken: AccessToken
    ) {
      if (currentAccessToken == null) {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
        textView!!.text = ""
        imageView!!.setImageResource(0)
      }
    }
  }

  override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking()
  }
}
```

I had have read in the internet for answer for this problem but i've could't find something that could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in Kotlin you have to specify the variable as nullable if it will be null in any case.

The error is in this function

```
var accessTokenTracker: AccessTokenTracker = object : AccessTokenTracker() {
    override fun onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
      oldAccessToken: AccessToken,
      currentAccessToken: AccessToken
    ) {
      if (currentAccessToken == null) {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
        textView!!.text = ""
        imageView!!.setImageResource(0)
      }
    }
  }
```

here in the onCurrentAccessTokenChanged() function you are expecting the currentAccessToken to be null, but you have not made currentAccessToken as nullable hence it will fail and crash. Since only nullable elements can get null value assigned after initialisation in Kotlin. Therefore here you can make the variables as nullable and the problem will be solved.

You can make any variable as nullable like this

`currentAccessToken : Type?` , where the Type can be Int, String or any supported or custom type.

```
var accessTokenTracker: AccessTokenTracker = object : AccessTokenTracker() {
    override fun onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
      oldAccessToken: AccessToken?,
      currentAccessToken: AccessToken?
    ) {
      if (currentAccessToken == null) {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
        textView!!.text = ""
        imageView!!.setImageResource(0)
      }
    }
  }
```

This will solve your problem.

It is always recommended that you make the variables as Nullable if you think that the variable might accommodate null at any time in the future in any case to avoid such crashes.